# How to change the text of textview more than one

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

Hi and sorry for my English! :)
I want to change the text of Text View after 3 second by random number but it's just show last number and I didn't see last numbers in Text View

What should I do?

Thanks... :)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    int rand;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView txtShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            rand = (int) (Math.random() * 9);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtShow.setText("" + rand);

                }
            }, 3000);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a loop. In this case you can use postDealyed to repost a runnable in the ui thread queue:

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

```
int rand;
int counter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView txtShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (counter > 4) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    return;
                }
                ++counter;
                rand = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
                txtShow.setText("" + rand);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

When counter reaches 5, `removeCallbacks` cancel all the runnables still present in the handler queue and returns. Otherwise counter is increased and `handler.postDelayed` add the runnable to the handler queue,

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
private Handler handler;
private TextView txt;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    handler = new Handler();
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    new Thread(new Task()).start();
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
                    txt.setText("" + rand);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of the `Runnable`s that are changing the `TextView` are executing right after one another; the change is so fast that you cannot see the intermediate values and instead only see the final value.

To fix your problem change the delay in `postDelayed()` from `3000` to `3000 * i`. This will ensure that the updates are spaced with 3 seconds between *each one* instead of just all executing 3 seconds after `onCreate()` finishes (as it is now).

For things like this you may also want to look into `Timer` (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)